# Various results with distinct() in a custom function

Tags: r

I want to create a function in R that will create a numerical column based on a character/categorical column. In order to do this I need to get the distinct values in the categorical column. I can do this outside a function well, but would like to make a reusable function to do it. The issue I've run into is that the same distinct() formula that works outside the function doesn't behave the same way within the formula. I've created a demo below:

```
# test of call to db to numericize
DF <- data.frame("a" = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                 "b" = paste(0:5, ".1", sep = ""),
                 "c" = letters[1:6],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

catnum <- function(db, inputcolname) {
  x <- distinct(db,inputcolname);
  print(x);
  return(x);
}

y <- distinct(DF,a)
y
catnum(DF,'a')
```

While y gives the correct distinct one column answer (one column with (a,b,c) in it), x within the function is the entire dataframe. I have tried with and without the ' ', as in catnum(DF,a) but the results are the same.

Could someone tell me what is happening or suggest some code that would work?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you would like the transformed data frame to look like? Thanks :)

Comment: You should mention that the `distinct` function can be found in the `dplyr` package (assuming that is actually the one you use).

Comment: The problem description made me think you were trying to re-invent the `factor` function (followed by `as.numeric`), but the accepted answer didn't seem to address that reading of the word "numericize".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `distinct_` function inside function. The `distinct` expect column name and it doesn't work with column names in a `variable`.

For example `distinct(DF, "a")` will not work. The actual syntax is: `distinct(DF, a)`. Notice the missing `quotes`. When `distinct` is called from function then column name was provided as variable name (i.e inputcolname) which was evaluated. Hence unexpected result. But `distinct_` works on variable name for columns.

```
library(dplyr)
catnum <- function(db, inputcolname) {
  x <- distinct_(db,inputcolname);
  #print(x);
  return(x);
}
#With modified function results were as expected.
catnum(DF,'a')
# a
# 1 a
# 2 b
# 3 c
```

Comment: This would be a good answer, except that the `distinct_` function is deprecated (and will presumably be removed at some point). See `?distinct_` and `vignette("programming")` for details.

Comment: @Ista I wasn't aware about that. Thanks for informing. Let me check.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do and where `distinct` function is coming from. Are you looking for this?

```
catnum<-function(DF,var){
  length(unique(DF[[var]]))
}
catnum(DF,'a')
```

Comment: Good alternate solution. Hence upvoted. Though it doesnt answer the OP's actual question why `distinct` function is not working.

Comment: I dont think "length" is needed as such.

Answer (score 1):

You're inputs are not the same, and so you get different results. If you give `distinct` the same arguments you give `catnum`, you will get the same result:

```
isTRUE(all.equal(distinct(DF, a),
                 catnum(DF, "a")))
## [1] FALSE
isTRUE(all.equal(distinct(DF, "a"),
                 catnum(DF, "a")))
##[1] TRUE
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
catnum(DF, a)
##   a   b c
## 1 a 0.1 a
## 2 b 1.1 b
## 3 c 2.1 c
## 4 a 3.1 d
## 5 b 4.1 e
## 6 c 5.1 f
```

The reason, as explained in

```
vignette("programming")
```

is that you must jump through several annoying hoops if you want to write functions that use functions from `dplyr`. The solution (as you will learn in the vignette) is as follows:

```
catnum <- function(db, inputcolname) {
  inputcolname <- enquo(inputcolname)  
  distinct(db, !!inputcolname)
}

catnum(DF, a)
##   a
## 1 a
## 2 b
## 3 c
```

Or you could conclude that this is all too confusing and do something like

```
catnum <- function(db, inputcolname) {
  unique(db[, inputcolname, drop = FALSE])
}

catnum(DF, "a")
##   a
## 1 a
## 2 b
## 3 c
```

instead.